# MongoDB error on execute function

Tags: php, mongodb, database

I have the following code for running a mongo query, Where the 'mongotester' is the DB name and 'categories' is the collection name

I am using PECL mongodb library

```
$m = new Mongo();
$db = $m->selectDB('mongotester');
$a = $db->execute('return mongotester.categories.count();');
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($a);
echo "<pre>";
```

When I am running this, I am getting the following error,

```
array(3) {
   ["errno"]=>
   float(-3)
  ["errmsg"]=>
     string(78) "invoke failed: JS Error: ReferenceError: mongotester is not defined     nofile_a:0"
  ["ok"]=>
  float(0)
}
```

Please help me to correct this.

thanks

[phpqa.in](http://phpqa.in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to execute() javascript for a count, you can reference the collection directly, eg:

```
$m = new Mongo();
$db = $m->selectDB('mongotester');
$a = $db->categories->count();
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($a);
echo "<pre>";
```

The var_dump in this case is just going to show int(0) unless you've actually inserted some data into the *categories* collection.

Comment: I know about this method, I want to use the 'reduce' functionality to find the count, based on MongoDB Query language.

Comment: Your example code with "execute()" doesn't really have anything to do with MapReduce.  Have a look at the [MongoDB::command() MapReduce example](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.command.php) in the PHP documentation instead.